# Sencha Touch 2 Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, notifications, touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch 2 application that needs to be able to push notifications.

I have 2 doubts:

1. Should I use the sencha notification implementation or is it better to use phoneGap?
2. How can I do to run the application on the background of the device, so I can be checking if a new notification is needed to be pushed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can natively manage IOS Push Notification with Sencha Touch 2.2 - http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Push

I've post on my blog how to configure and build a Sencha Touch application for IOS Push Notifications - [http://isolasoftware.it/2013/09/17/ios-push-notifications-using-sencha-touch-2](http://isolasoftware.it/2013/09/17/ios-push-notifications-using-sencha-touch-2/)/.

The most important steps are:

- Configure applicationName, applicationId and bundleSeedId in package.json
- Perform a manual entitlement on your app
- Build the .pem certificate (or .p12) for push server correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about native Apple's push notifications, then Sencha doesn't support it. You have to use PhoneGap + [Cordova PushNotification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification). This plugin was implemented by [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/), so I'm not sure whether this plugin usage is free or not...